# CS50 initials.c spacing bug?

Tags: c, cs50

The code is suppose to print the initials of the users but the code has a bug instead it prints out the whole name with spaces between each letter. I know the bug lies in the for loop but im not sure how to debug this issue. Suggestions?

```
int main(void)
{
 printf("Enter full name: ");
 string name = get_string();

    {
        printf("%c", toupper(name[0]));
    }

 for(int i = 0, n = strlen(name); i < n; i++)  
 {
     printf(" ");

     printf("%c", toupper(name[i + 1]));
 }

}
```

Comment: Your loop loops round over every single character - what else do you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to split `name` into tokens separated by spaces, then print only the first letter of each token. You can use `strtok()` to split it.

Comment: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you mean to test to see if the next char is a space, and if it is, then print the char following the space:

```
if (name[i] == ' ')
{
    printf("%c", toupper(name[i + 1]));
}
```

Of course, before the `for` loop, you need to print the first initial since there won't be a space before it:

```
// print the first initial before the loop
cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(toupper(name[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly printing the characters, but you have `printf(" ");` so no wonder why there are spaces here.

Comment: He's not correctly printing the characters. He's only supposed to print the initials, not all the characters in the name.

Comment: Yeah that's what he said, at the same time he focuses on a mistake *inside* the for loop... Well,  I guess it's unclear.